# Botón error con CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3

[Aquí está el código](https://codepen.io/padr-n-rocha/pen/eYYpvXN)

Este proyecto tiene como objetivo decorar unos botones, el caso es que sólo hace el efecto en un sólo boton (Me refiero al momento de cliquear el boton, salga un menu emergente) Si todo el boton N2 el efecto solo se realiza en el boton N1 en vez del boton M2.

No sé si con un ejemplo de JavaScript se pueda hacer

Comment: El problema que estas teniendo es que repites el id="active_boton". Los ids deben ser unicos y si quieres reusar el mismo nombre deberias usar la propiedad name o class. Luego ya como opinion personal, la "funcionalidad" de una web deberias dejarsela al codigo javascript y dejar que el CSS se encargue de los estilos, que para eso fue creado. Pero esto ya es una opinion.

Comment: Así es, correcto con lo que dice Narshe los 2 botones tienen la misma funcionalidad asi que sugiera que diferencies el active_boton2.